# React create one styled components for two different icons?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

So I am using react icons and I have two different icons that I am styling with styled components. My issue is that they essentially have the exact same styles, but the only difference is which icon I am choosing to style.

I don't know how to combine both icons into one styled component

Here is my code

```
      const backArrow = styled(IoArrowBack)`
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
      `;

      const forwardArrow = styled(IoArrowForward)`
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
      `;
```

Since I am using styled components, I just pass the icon into the `()` based on which one I want to style. The issue is I have over 12 lines of the exact same styles for both icons. It doesn't make sense to repeat the exact styles

How would I create one styled component, but display two different icons?

Example concept like this

```
 const arrowIcon = styled(IoArrowBack, IoArrowForward)`
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
 `
```

But then the issue occurs if I were to add them to my JSX

Cause then how would I even add the code?

I can't do

```
  <arrrowIcon>Back arrow</arrowIcon>
  <arrrowIcon>Forward arrow</arrowIcon>
```

So it wouldn't know which icon is which.

Is this even possible with styled components, or would I just have to copy and paste the same styles for each icon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This piece of code is a bit weird to me, I think this is not a valid code

```
const arrowIcon = styled(IoArrowBack, IoArrowForward)`
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
     `
```

However you can do a trick to get a shared style

```
const sharedIconStyle = css`
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
`
```

And

```
   const styledArowBack= styled(IoArrowBack)`
       ${sharedIconStyle}
      `   
   const styledArrowForward = styled(IoArrowForward)`
       ${sharedIconStyle}
      `;
```

Comment: ah yeah that line was just the "logic" but doesn't actually work. But your share styled method ended up working

Answer (score 0):

Could you just do it with React?

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

import { ReactComponent as icon1 } from "./icons/1.svg";
import { ReactComponent as icon2 } from "./icons/2.svg";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <SizedIcon Icon={icon1} />
      <SizedIcon Icon={icon2} />
    </div>
  );
}

const SizedIcon = ({ size = 50, Icon }) => {
  console.log(typeof Icon);
  return (
    <div>
      <Icon width={size} height={size} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit affectionate-breeze-v5bxn]

Answer (score 0):

What I did is wrapped the icons in a div and styled the div, for example change the icon colors to red:

```
const IconStyles = styled.div`
  color: red;
`

<IconStyles> 
  <IoArrowBack />
</IconStyles> 

<IconStyles> 
  <IoArrowForward />
</IconStyles>
```

If you want to change the size of the icons then add a font-size in the div containing the icons, that is how I personally do it.